# ASP.NET Web App Crashing Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Every time i go to create a new ASP.NET Web App in visual Studio , VS keeps crashing and restarts?

Im using VS Professional 2013

Comment: Are you running VS add ons?

Comment: Sorry not over sure how would i check.

Comment: Cheers located what am i looking for ?